# Codeigniter similar data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can I make it in the code so that duplicates from the base of some particular column are not displayed? For example, I have a column of transaction_id, that is ID is actually from a paypal, and I would like to not be displayed twice in the table on the client part, but it's not forbidden to repeat the same id, so I can not set that column unique in the database. Actually my question is how do I create a code to watch this column and if there's a duplicate that does not show both, but only one in the code?
I have this code, maybe i can put here something?

```
function get_all_Invoices()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('ID');
        $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
        $this->db->where('error', '0');
        $this->db->where('generated', '0');
        return $this->db->get_where('invoices_requests', array('send'=>0))->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: you can $this->db->group_by('your-key');

Comment: That works, thanks! :)

Comment: Please mark this comment as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` function in your SQL query

```
$this->db->distinct('your-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group_by function

```
$this->db->group_by('your_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$query = $this->db->group_by('your_id')
                  ->where('delete', '0')
                  ->where('error', '0')
                  ->where('generated', '0')
                  ->where('send', '0')
                  ->get('invoices_requests');

return $query->result_array();
```

Or

```
$array = array('delete' => '0', 'error' => '0', 'generated' => '0', 'send' => '0');

$query = $this->db->group_by('ID')
                  ->where($array)
                  ->get('invoices_requests');

return $query->result_array();
```